# In Rust, what's the difference between "{}" and "{:?}" inside a println!?

Tags: rust

This code works:

```
let x = Some(2);
println!("{:?}", x);
```

But this does not:

```
let x = Some(2);
println!("{}", x);
```

```
5 | println!("{}", x);
  |                ^ trait `std::option::Option: std::fmt::Display` not satisfied
  |
  = note: `std::option::Option` cannot be formatted with the default formatter; try using `:?` instead if you are using a format string
  = note: required by `std::fmt::Display::fmt`
```

Why? What's `:?` in that context?

Answer (score 15):

`{:?}`, or, specifically, `?`, is the placeholder used by the `Debug` trait. If the type does not implement `Debug`, then using `{:?}` in a format string breaks.

For example:

```
struct MyType {
    the_field: u32
}

fn main() {
    let instance = MyType { the_field: 5000 };
    println!("{:?}", instance);
}
```

..fails with:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `MyType: std::fmt::Debug` is not satisfied
```

[Implementing `Debug` though, fixes that](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1a0957c017ae7d0b8a11ec90ba1f9cd5&version=stable&backtrace=0):

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyType {
    the_field: u32
}

fn main() {
    let instance = MyType { the_field: 5000 };
    println!("{:?}", instance);
}
```

Which outputs: `MyType { the_field: 5000 }`.

You can see a list of these placeholder/operators [in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/).